# math software for associative algebras (usual not commutative)

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-software

Does anyone if there exists a math program that can work with free associative algebras ? By work with associative algebras, I mean

- It can define any ideal $I$, being it left-,right- or twosided.
- It can define quotientrings $R/I$ and I can do summation and multiplication in it. (if it can work only with ideals generated by homogeneous elements, it's ok).
- It can calculate elements of the center of an associatieve algebra(= a quotient of a free algebra) of a certain degree (I don't need to find the complete center, just the elements of a certain degree).

Additionally, it would be nice if it were free (opensource or something like that) and it works on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Forgot to mention: if it can be done in Sage, is there any good documentation on how to do those things ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sagemath : there is a documentation about how to manipulate free algebras. But unfortunately, sagemath is linux native and isn't optimized for Windows...

Comment: Does it do all those things ? The only examples I find give finite dimensional algebras and $R/I$ only works in the case $I$ is a power ideal (if I copy the code from sagemath.org-quotient rings).